# Restoring ORACLE 11gR2 database with Flash Recovery Area Only

Tags: oracle, rman

I was succeded in making backup using RMAN in Archivelog mode in my host server and this is the screenshot when i list the backup,

[image]

and the next step, i copy content from Flash Recovery Area folder inside BACKUPSET Folder to a new host to execute the restore.

but unfortunately when i logged in to the new host and issue list backup command in rman, I cant see any backup file thus i cant restore the database. Please help me was there anything missing in my procedure ??

Thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Just start `rman`, and issue the command:

```
CATALOG START WITH 'c:\path\to\your\backups';
```

... and it'll prompt you for confirmation & add the backups to the `rman` catalog.

Comment: Phil, thanks for your help but im getting this error, 
RMAN-07518: Reason: Foreign database file DBID: 3183549080  Database Name: WELTES